# Configure fluentd to properly parse and ship java stacktrace,which is formatted using docker json-file logging driver,to elastic as single message

Tags: docker, fluentd

Our service runs as a docker instance.
Given limitation is that the docker logging driver cannot be changed to anything different than the default json-file driver.
The (scala micro)service outputs a log that looks like this

```
{"log":"10:30:12.375 [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] [WARN] [rulekeepr-615239361-v5mtn-7]- c.v.r.s.logic.RulekeeprLogicProvider(91) - decision making have failed unexpectedly\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376485994Z"}
{"log":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Error extracting fields to make a lookup for a rule at P2: [failed calculating amount/amountEUR/directive: [failed getting accountInfo of companyId:3303 from deadcart: unexpected status returned: 500]]\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376528449Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.assbox.rulekeepr.services.BasicRuleService$$anonfun$lookupRule$2.apply(BasicRuleService.scala:53)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376537277Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.assbox.rulekeepr.services.BasicRuleService$$anonfun$lookupRule$2.apply(BasicRuleService.scala:53)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376542826Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$transform$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Future.scala:224)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376548224Z"}
{"log":"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed calculating amount/amountEUR/directive: [failed getting accountInfo of companyId:3303 from deadcart: unexpected status returned: 500]\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376674554Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.assbox.rulekeepr.services.logic.TlrComputedFields$$anonfun$calculatedFields$1.applyOrElse(AbstractComputedFields.scala:39)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376680922Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.assbox.rulekeepr.services.logic.TlrComputedFields$$anonfun$calculatedFields$1.applyOrElse(AbstractComputedFields.scala:36)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376686377Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376691228Z"}
{"log":"\u0009... 19 common frames omitted\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376720255Z"}
{"log":"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed getting accountInfo of companyId:3303 from deadcart: unexpected status returned: 500\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376724303Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.assbox.rulekeepr.services.mixins.DCartHelper$$anonfun$accountInfo$1.apply(DCartHelper.scala:31)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376729945Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.assbox.rulekeepr.services.mixins.DCartHelper$$anonfun$accountInfo$1.apply(DCartHelper.scala:24)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.376734254Z"}
{"log":"\u0009... 19 common frames omitted\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-05-08T10:30:12.37676087Z"}
```

How can I harness fluentd directives for properly combining the following log event that contains a stack trace, so it all be shipped to elastic as single message?

I have full control of the logback appender pattern used, so I can change the order of occurrence of log values to something else, and even change the appender class.

We're working with k8s and it turns out its not straight forward to change the docker logging driver so we're looking for a solution that will be able to handle the given example.

I don't care so much about extracting the loglevel, thread, logger into specific keys so I could later easily filter by them in kibana. it would be nice to have, but less important.
What is important is to accurately parse the timestamp, down to the milliseconds and use it as the actual log even timestamp as it shipped to elastic.

Comment: You could write a grok filter to filter the date from the message into another field (potentially overwrite the json time field) and a datefilter that takes the timestamp from the timefield and overwrites elastics @timestamp. Its still one logentry per line but at least you have everything searchable in kibana

Comment: @herm 10x, but I'm looking for a concrete fluentd example. And grok is a logstash feature

Comment: Sorry I though you are using the entire elk stack. I can't help then

Comment: Instead of using docker logging driver, you could run fluentd as a sidecar in the same pod as your app and share your log file as a volume.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fluent-plugin-concat](https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-concat).

For example with Fluentd v0.14.x,

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  tag kubernetes.*
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
  @label @INPUT
</source>

<label @INPUT>
  <filter kubernetes.**>
    @type concat
    key log
    multiline_start_regexp ^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+
    continuous_line_regexp ^(\s+|java.lang|Caused by:)
    separator ""
    flush_interval 3s
    timeout_label @PARSE
  </filter>
  <match kubernetes.**>
    @type relabel
    @label @PARSE
  </match>
</label>

<label @PARSE>
  <filter kubernetes.**>
    @type parser
    key_name log
    inject_key_prefix log.
    <parse>
      @type multiline_grok
      grok_failure_key grokfailure
      <grok>
        pattern YOUR_GROK_PATTERN
      </grok>
    </parse>
  </filter>
  <match kubernetes.**>
    @type relabel
    @label @OUTPUT
  </match>
</label>

<label @OUTPUT>
  <match kubernetes.**>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</label>
```

Similar issues:

- https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-grok-parser/issues/36
- https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-grok-parser/issues/37

Comment: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-concat-2.4.0/lib/fluent/plugin/filter_concat.rb:98:in `initialize': end pattern with unmatched parenthesis: /(\s+|java.lang|Caused by:/ (RegexpError)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the fluentd-plugin-grok-parser - but I am having the same issue - it seems that the \u0009 tab character is not being recognized and so using fluentd-plugin-detect-exceptions will not detect the multiline exceptions - at least not yet in my attempts... .

Answer (score 0):

In fluentd 1.0 I was able to achieve this with fluent-plugin-concat. The concat plugin starts and continues concatenation until it sees multiline_start_regexp pattern again. This captures JAVA exceptions and multiline slf4j log statements. Adjust your multiline_start_regexp pattern to match your slf4j log output line.

Any line, including exceptions starting starting with a timestamp matching pattern **2020-10-05 18:01:52.871**
will be concatenated
ex:

```
2020-10-05 18:01:52.871 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8088-exec-3] c.i.printforever.DemoApplication multiline statement
```

I am using container_id as the identity key,

```
<system>
  log_level debug
</system>
# Receive events from 24224/tcp
# This is used by log forwarding and the fluent-cat command
<source>
  @type  forward
  @id    input1
  @label @mainstream
  port  24224
</source>
# All plugin errors
<label @ERROR>
    <match **>
        @type file
        @id   error
        path /fluentd/log/docker/error/error.%Y-%m-%d.%H%M
        compress gzip
        append true
        <buffer>
          @type file
          path /fluentd/log/docker/error
          timekey 60s
          timekey_wait 10s
          timekey_use_utc true
          total_limit_size 200mb
        </buffer>
      </match>
</label>
<label @mainstream>
    <filter docker.**>
        @type concat
        key log
        stream_identity_key container_id
        multiline_start_regexp /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}/
    </filter>
    # Match events with docker tag
    # Send them to S3
    <match docker.**>
      @type copy
      <store>
        @type s3
        @id output_docker_s3
        aws_key_id "#{ENV['AWS_KEY_ID']}"
        aws_sec_key "#{ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY']}"
        s3_bucket "#{ENV['S3_BUCKET']}"
        path "#{ENV['S3_OBJECT_PATH']}"
        store_as gzip
        <buffer tag,time>
          @type file
          path /fluentd/log/docker/s3
          timekey 300s
          timekey_wait 1m
          timekey_use_utc true
          total_limit_size 200mb
        </buffer>
        time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H
      </store>
      <store>
        @type stdout
      </store>
      <store>
        @type file
        @id   output_docker_file
        path /fluentd/log/docker/file/${tag}.%Y-%m-%d.%H%M
        compress gzip
        append true
        <buffer tag,time>
          @type file
          timekey_wait 1m
          timekey 1m
          timekey_use_utc true
          total_limit_size 200mb
          path /fluentd/log/docker/file/
        </buffer>
      </store>
    </match>
    <match **>
      @type file
      @id   output_file
      path   /fluentd/log/docker/catch-all/data.*.log
    </match>
</label>
```