# Using fluentd to parse the docker json-file log which is in the /var/lib/docker/containter/*/* as a common way?

Tags: java, docker, logging, kubernetes, fluent

There are some ways to collect docker or k8s containter logs:

1. using stream log driver like gelf, fluent etc, but this can not using *docker logs* command to debug, So it is not a good way to solve the problems. [Send log to multiple log drivers](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/17910)[Enhance local logging / remote logging](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33475)

Because the docker's log driver can not support multiline,the logs in /var/lib/docker/containter/*/*.json is line by line[log driver should support multiline](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22920).

2. Using log collector program like filebeat, fluend, collector-sidecar,logstash to parse the docker json file in  /var/lib/docker/containter/*/*. But I still can not find 
   a good ways to collect the logs.

---

After a few days of searching, I think the fluent is the best tools to solve this question and find two ways to solve the problem. But I still solve my problems.

1. using the [fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/10289) + gelf, but this still be two message. [Docker logs (Java stack trace that are long) NOT meaningful in Splunk](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/10289) [Is available to concat stack trace and previous line with error message](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions/issues/34)

The origin log:

```
 {"log":"2018-04-19 14:19:57,915 INFO  [FixedTimeScheduler] com.testjavatest.fastdemo.ws.WebSocketClientManager: send ws message -{TAB} for envirnem -{{\"res\":\"heartbeat\"}}\n","stream":"stdou
 t","time":"2018-04-19T06:19:57.916259717Z"}
 {"log":"2018-04-19 14:19:57,915 INFO  [FixedTimeScheduler] com.testjavatest.fastdemo.ws.WebSocketClientManager: send ws message -{TAB} for envirnem -{{\"res\":\"heartbeat\"}}\n","stream
 ":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:19:57.916265977Z"}
 {"log":"2018-04-19 14:20:43,446 ERROR [FixedTimeScheduler] com.testjavatest.fastdemo.task.JobTask: Connect to cloud.testjavatest.com:5002 [cloud.testjavatest.com/10.111.2.77] failed: Connection timed o
 ut (Connection timed out)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448436321Z"}
 {"log":"org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to cloud.testjavatest.com:5002 [cloud.testjavatest.com/10.111.2.77] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)\n","stream":"s
 tdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448475801Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.4484860
 6Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448492586
 Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448498085Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448503302Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.4485085Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448527373Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448532363Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.44853704Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448541864Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448546452Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448551288Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at com.testjavatest.httpclient.MyHttpClient.send(MyHttpClient.java:308)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448555115Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at com.testjavatest.httpclient.MyHttpClient.send(MyHttpClient.java:264)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448559028Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at com.testjavatest.httpclient.MyHttpClient.recvBytes(MyHttpClient.java:470)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448563048Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at com.testjavatest.httpclient.MyHttpClient.recvString(MyHttpClient.java:474)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448567524Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at com.testjavatest.httpclient.MyHttpClient.recvJSON(MyHttpClient.java:483)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448571872Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at com.testjavatest.fastdemo.task.JobTask.run(JobTask.java:70)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448576282Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at com.testjavatest.fastdemo.task.timer.FixedTimeScheduler.run(FixedTimeScheduler.java:43)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.44858108Z"}
 {"log":"Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448585665Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448590045Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448596151Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448600888Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448605225Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448609704Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448614111Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:337)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448618537Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.4486230
 34Z"}
 {"log":"\u0009... 17 more\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:43.448627326Z"}
 {"log":"2018-04-19 14:20:57,934 INFO  [FixedTimeScheduler] com.testjavatest.fastdemo.config.WsJobTask: ws heartbeat run\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-04-19T06:20:57.934646438Z"}
```

The expect output in gelf:

one java event is one not multiline.

My fluent config is:

```
  <source>
  @id fluentd-containers.log
  @type tail
  path "/var/lib/docker/containers/52b26345771ff24b76840a57f26808562aea0e917d72746d48aac6f9870b901b/52b26345771ff24b76840a57f26808562aea0e917d72746d48aac6f9870b901b-json.log"
  pos_file "/var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos"
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  tag "raw.docker.*"
  format json
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
    @type json
    time_type string
  </parse>
</source>
<match raw.docker.**>
  @id raw.docker
  @type detect_exceptions
  remove_tag_prefix "raw"
  message "log"
  stream "stream"
  languages java, python
  multiline_flush_interval 5
  max_bytes 0
  max_lines 0
</match>
<match docker.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type "gelf"
    protocol "udp"
    host "192.168.2.4"
    port 12206
    flush_interval 5s
    <buffer>
      flush_mode interval
      retry_type exponential_backoff
      flush_interval 5s
    </buffer>
  </store>
  <store>
    @type "stdout"
  </store>
</match>
```

But this can not work, could someone give me a hand?

2. using the [fluent-plugin-grok-parser](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-grok-parser) +[fluent-plugin-concat](https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-concat.)+ gelf, but this still can not work.
   the help message:[Handle multiline with empty line from kubernetes/docker with --log-driver=json-file](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-grok-parser/issues/37) and [Multiple grok patterns with multiline not parsing the log](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-grok-parser/issues/36)
   [the same question](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845712/configure-fluentd-to-properly-parse-and-ship-java-stacktrace-which-is-formatted/47543327#47543327)
   the message is as above and the expect output is as expected above.

my fluent config is:

```
   <source>
   @id fluentd-containers.log
   @type tail
   from_encoding UTF-8
   encoding UTF-8
   path /var/lib/docker/containers/52b26345771ff24b76840a57f26808562aea0e917d72746d48aac6f9870b901b/52b26345771ff24b76840a57f26808562aea0e917d72746d48aac6f9870b901b-json.log
   pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
   time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
   tag raw.docker.*
   format json
   read_from_head true
 </source>
 <filter raw.docker.**> 
   @type grep
   regexp1 stream stdout
   @type concat
   key log
   multiline_start_regexp /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\,\d+/ 
   continuous_line_regexp /^\s+/ 
   separator ""
   flush_interval 3s
 </filter>
 <filter raw.docker.**>
   @type parser
   key_name log
   inject_key_prefix log.
   <parse>
     @type multiline_grok
     grok_failure_key grokfailure
     <grok>
       pattern /%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_time}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:threadname}\]%{SPACE}%{DATA:classname}%{SPACE}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}/ 
     </grok>
   </parse>
 </filter>
 <match raw.docker.**>
   @type copy
   <store>
     @type gelf
     protocol udp
     host 10.111.2.4
     port 12204
     flush_interval 5s
   </store>
   <store>
     @type stdout
   </store>
   <store>
     @type file
     path /var/log/test
   </store> 
 </match>
```

But this can not work, could someone give me a hand? thanks.

---

PS: I want to know is there a better way to collect docker logs ?